# Question on Construction in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, induced transformations

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

First I quote the relevant passage (page 89):

> If we consider now a differentiable function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ we have a linear transformation $Df(p): \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. Another minor modification therefore produces a linear transformation $f_*: \mathbb R^n_p \to \mathbb R^m_{f(p)}$ defined by
>   $$
>  f_*(v_p) = (Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}.
> $$
>   This linear transformation induces a linear transformation $f^* : \Lambda^k(\mathbb R^m_{f(p)}) \to \Lambda^k(\mathbb R^n_p)$. If $\omega$ is a $k$-form on $\mathbb R^m$ we can therefore define a $k$-form $f^*\omega$ on $\mathbb R^n$ by $(f^*\omega)(p) = f^*(\omega(f(p)))$. Recall this means that if $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb R^n_p$, then we have $f^*\omega(p)(v_1, \ldots, v_k) = \omega(f(p))(f_*(v_1), \ldots, f_*(v_k))$.

The last paragraph makes no sense to me, the first one is quite clear, but I don't see what the induces $f^*$ should be for a transformation, and why it is alternating (of course I know that each linear transformation $f:V\to W$ induces
one $f^*$ on multilinear transformations by $f^*(T)(v_1,\ldots,v_k) = T(f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_k))$, but this is not alternating in general)? How to come from $f_*$ to a function $f^*$ on the space of alternating multilinear function with $k$ arguments...

Okay, for completeness I collect the relevant definitions:

(1)

> If $p \in \mathbb R^n$, the set of all pairs $(p,v)$, for $v \in \mathbb R^n$, is denoted $R^n_p$, and called the **tangent space** of $\mathbb R^n$ at $p$. This set is made into a vector space in the most obvious way, by defining
>   $$
>  (p,v) + (p,w) = (p,v+w) \quad a\cdot (p,v) = (p, av).
> $$

(2) $Df(p)$ denotes the linear approximation of $f$ at $p$, also called the **derivative** of $f$ at $p$.

(3) The set $\Lambda^k(V)$ is the set of all alternating $k$-tensors, i.e. alternating multilinear functions $T: V^k \to \mathbb R$. Similarly $\mathcal I^k(V)$ denotes the space of all $k$-tensors on $V$.

(4) If $f : V \to W$ is a linear transformation, a linear transformation $f^* : \mathcal I^k(W) \to \mathcal I^k(V)$ is defined by
$$
 f^*T(v_1, \ldots, v_k) = T(f(v_1), \ldots, f(v_k))
$$
for $T \in \mathcal I^k(W)$ and $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in V$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I don't see what the induces $f^∗$ should be for a transformation'? Also, you don't see 'why it is alternating'; what is 'it' that you are referring to?

Comment: I mean the induces transformation $f^* : \Lambda^k(\mathbb R^m_{f(p)}) \to \Lambda^k(\mathbb R^n_p)$. I do not see why it is alternating, I think it is constructed by what I quoted under (4), but maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: What does it mean for $f^*$ to be alternating?

Comment: A multilinear transformation $\omega :V^k \to \mathbb R$ (or $k$-tensor) is called alternating if $\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_k) = -\omega(v_1,\ldots, v_j,\ldots, v_i,\ldots,v_k)$, meaning transposing two arguments changes the sign.

Comment: That's what it means for a $k$-tensor to be alternating, $f^*$ is not a $k$-tensor, $f^*$ is a map $\bigwedge^k(\mathbb{R}^m_{f(p)}) \to \bigwedge^k(\mathbb{R}^n_p)$.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by 'I don't see what the induces $f^∗$ should be for a transformation'.

Comment: yes, for $f^*$ it does not make any sense to say it is alternating, so that it is just the $f^*$ under (4) restricted to all alternating $k$-tensors, and then the image is also an alternating $k$-tensor. Okay now everything is clear to me. I was not sure how the $f^*$ is defined, but now it is clear: it is the $f^*$ from (4) restricted to the alternating tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have figured out all the answers yourself (see the comments to the question), but let me try to summarise.

It makes no sense to talk about $f^*$ being alternating as it is not a tensor, but rather a map $\bigwedge^k(\mathbb{R}^m_{f(p)}) \to \bigwedge^k(\mathbb{R}^n_p)$. The only thing that one may feel the need to verify is that $(f^*\omega)(p)$ really is alternating.

Comment: If I am mistaken and you still have unanswered questions from the post above, let me know and I will try to answer them.

Comment: Now I understand, that $(f*\omega)(p)$ is alternating is also clear to me for $k$-forms $\omega$ (and hence functions from points to alternating tensors). thx!